# How do I make my Mozilla Firefox (Marrionete) profile remember a login?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have created this script with Python Selenium to automate some things, and I have had problems with one website recently. It might be that they incorporated something in the background, and now login doesn't work. It says that password and email don't match, but they do. When I try to login without selenium, it works.

Until now, script would go to the website, login, and do what needed to be done. But now it's almost impossible to login with Selenium.

The code would look something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

print('Opening FireFox...')

geckodriver_path = '/usr/bin/geckodriver'
firefox_profile_path = '/home/m41/.mozilla/firefox/pilqp6x7.default-release'
firefox_service = FirefoxService(executable_path=geckodriver_path, log_output="geckodriver.log")
options = Options()
options.set_preference("profile", firefox_profile_path)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=firefox_service, options=options)

print('Firefox is ready!')
time.sleep(2)
print('Connecting to the Website...')
browser.get('https://mywebsite.com')
time.sleep(2)
print('Login in progress...')
time.sleep(2)
login_button = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'nav-login-trigger').click()
time.sleep(10)
email_field = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@qa-id="login-model-email"]').send_keys(em) #em is email for this website
pass_field = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@qa-id="login-model-pw"]').send_keys(pw) #pw is my password for this website
time.sleep(7)
signin_button = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'login_login_1ss').click()
time.sleep(11)
print('Login finished!')
time.sleep(22)
browser.get('https://mywebsite.com/dashboard-studio')
... rest of the code...`
```

I have tried to create new profiles with Firefox but it used to work for some time, but now it doesn't work in any profile. But it does work if I login manually.

Now I'm thinking of creating a profile where I would already be logged in. I could log in manually and have the script start from there.

The code would look like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

print('Opening FireFox...')

geckodriver_path = '/usr/bin/geckodriver'
firefox_profile_path = '/home/m41/.mozilla/firefox/pilqp6x7.default-release'
firefox_service = FirefoxService(executable_path=geckodriver_path, log_output="geckodriver.log")
options = Options()
options.set_preference("profile", firefox_profile_path)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=firefox_service, options=options)

print('Firefox is ready!')
time.sleep(2)
print('Connecting to the Website...')
browser.get('https://mywebsite.com/dashboard-studio')
... rest of the code...
```

Does anyone have similar issues or have any idea how I can make this work?

Thanks in advance!